# Converting HTML String into pdf and sending through REST

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, html, pdf

I have a string having HTML content with me inside a apex method(this class is not linked to any vf page). I need to convert the HTML on the fly into pdf and send through rest API.

I know we can create a VF page with output text and add the HTML string as value to it like this:

```
 <apex:outputText value="{!testPDFData}" escape="false" />
```

and get the content of VF page as pdf using below:

```
PageReference pdftest = Page.pdftest; 
Blob pdfBlob = pdftest.getContentAsPDF();
```

But how do I add the string HTML content from my apex class method to this VF page. As there is no UI interaction involved here.

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need to get Visualforce involved, as you can use the Blob.toPdf function:

```
Blob pdfFile = Blob.valueOf(outputText);
```

There are some limitations to this usage compared to Visualforce, but as long as you're using standard HTML, it should come out more-or-less as you expect.

Comment: I tried using this. I got the Blob. But when I convert it into base64 using EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfBlob) and use the resulted string to see the pdf using online tools it is showing Failed to load PDF document.  Will third party be able to use my blob and get pdf out of it?

Comment: @PKSF The base-64 encoded version would have to be decoded first. Try emailing it to yourself using a EmailFileAttachment to email a copy to yourself (do *not* use base-64 encoding). As far sending it over the wire via REST, you'll need to use the appropriate format for whatever the third-party service needs to handle the data.

Comment: I didn't read your answer correctly I guess, I used  Blob.toPdf() now(earlier I was using Blob.valueOf()), it worked partially - 1) It is throwing error if I am using images into it.  2) It is not apply the CSS, rather taking the CSS as string inside converted PDF. How Can I make sure to apply the CSS codes present in the String.

Comment: While Using img with src tag it is throwing 'An error occurred while parsing the input string' error.

Comment: how are you embedding the CSS in your string?